# What are Hero Points in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-sheets

I've just downloaded an Excel character sheet, and it has a slot for Hero Points. I have many of the official 5e books (the *Player's Handbook*, MM, DMG, SCAG, VGtM, MToF, and XGtE), and I'm fairly sure it isn't in any of them.

Is it homebrew, or from a different realm? Is it just a different name for something I know about, or am I just being thick?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Hero Points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#HeroPoints) are found on page 264 of the DMG.

> With this option, a character starts with 5 hero point at 1st level. [...] A player can spend a hero point whenever he or she makes an attack roll, an ability check, or a saving throw. The player can spend the hero point after the roll is made but before any of its results are applied. Spending the hero point allows the player to roll a d6 and add it to the d20, possibly turning a failure into a success. A player can spend only 1 hero point per roll.

Comment: Thank you,  found it, just when I thought I was getting to grips with this I find something new. I was just being thick:)

Comment: @DaleGray Note that it's an entirely optional system that is designed for epic fantasy settings (PCs are more akin to superheroes than standard adventurers) so it may not fit your setting and you're not required to use it.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that there are other ways of handling the concept of hero points. I've seen some people run DnD 5e campaigns with hero point rules similar to Pathfinder 2e's rules (you start with none, get 1 at the start of every session, have a max equal to character level plus 2, and spending one gets you a reroll instead of adding 1d6). You still end up with a much higher success rate on average for the party no matter how you use them though, especially as you get to higher levels.

Comment: This seems very similar to Star Wars Saga Edition's Force Points system that allows players to spend FP to add a d6 to any skill check, ability check, or attack roll. In that system, players also start with 5 at level 1. However, they can be used to augment Force Powers and other feats for a turn, boosting their power temporarily. I'm curious if Saga Edition was the first system to do this.

Comment: Thank you all for your help I'm  fairly new to this and have only played with 2 groups to date, I'm fairly obsessive though so I've read a lot on the subject, but other than a few trials with my 10 year old daughter, I haven't attempted to DM yet so that's the only book I possess that i haven't read from cover to cover yet.

Comment: @dave20 Pretty sure that they’re based off of the Action Points from the 3.5 book *Eberron Campaign Setting*.